# I cannot install anything from windows store

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have tried so many things, nothing is working.

This is my error while installing any app.

[image]

On clicking "see details", this is what I gets:

[image]

Windows update is turned on. Now I have tried many things:

1. Reset troubleshooter for apps.

It gives me below error:

[image]

No matter, what I do, this cache is not getting fixed. I do not have any cache folder in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState.

I have also tried everything here : https://appuals.com/fix-windows-store-cache-may-be-damaged-windows-10/

Can anyone help me.

Comment: I had this same exact problem. The only fix was for me to create a whole new user account, transfer everything there, and then delete the old account. An application such as RegEditX helps greatly with the registry updates.

Comment: What build of Windows 10 are you using?

Comment: @Ramhound: My build is 15063.632

Comment: @Bill Oertell: I also created a new user account. That account is also having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The code `0x80070422` means `ERROR_SERVICE_DISABLED`

> The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or
>   because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

So it looks like you disabled the AppX Deployment service (AppXSVC) in service.msc

Comment: No, AppX Deployment service is running.

Comment: have you stopped any other services?

Comment: No. I have not stopped any service.